# Integral of 1D array in Fortran

Tags: fortran, integral, calculus

The task is to write the code for calculating integral of the polynomial function.[image] the function id displayed in the image I attached. I wrote the code and it compiled and the answer came out. However, it is completely different with the analytical solution. The code:

```
     program rectangularApproximation
     
     write(*,*) "Input values of a ,b and eps"
     read(*,*) a,b,eps



1    continue
     n=1000
     h=(b-a)/n
     s=0.0
     do i=1,n
         x=a+h*i
         s=s+f(x)*h
     enddo

     sprev=s
     n=10*n

     h=(b-a)/n

     s=0.0

     do i=1,n
         x=a+h*i
         s=s+f(x)*h
     enddo

     snext=s

     if (abs(sprev-snext)<eps) then
         write(*,*) snext,n
         stop
     end if
         goto 1

     write(*,*) s
     end
       real function f(x)

            implicit none
            real, intent(in)    :: x
            integer             :: i
            real, dimension(8) :: numbers
            numbers = (/1,3,1,4,2,3,0,1 /)


            do i = 1,8
                f = f + numbers(i) * x**(numbers(i))
            end do
        end function
```

The result obtained by running the code is   588189248  (the interval (a,b) is (1,2) and i chose epsillon=0.001) Analytical solution is following :
[image]

The answer of analytical solution is 169.256 . What could have gone wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial code is wrong:

```
            do i = 1,8
                f = f + numbers(i) * x**(numbers(i))
            end do
```

That should be

```
            do i = 1,8
                f = f + numbers(i) * x**i
            end do
```

Comment: Oh I corrected it and now it`s showing 2.16091034E+09 :(

Comment: You never zero f before performing calculations either

Comment: You're going to have to debug print some intermediate values.   I wrote Python code that mirrors yours, and I get 168.965 with n=1000 and 169.225 with n=10000.  The individual values of the function range from 15 to 598, do I don't know how you're getting 2 billion.

Comment: Debugging print statement can be your friend here. One usually only needs to do them up to I=2 in the loop.